# View isn't working after pressing the back button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, surfaceview

So i have 3 Activites (LauncherActivity>MenuActivity>SelectionActivity).
Basically you should always be able to return to the previous activity (exept the LauncherActivity). 
Everything works fine but when i want to return with the back button from the SelectionActivity to the MenuActivity the View shows just a black screen. But the ontouchlistener still works.

The MenuActivity uses a surfaceview, with a thread.

Part from the MenuView:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            if (menuThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            {
                menuThread.setRunning(true);
                menuThread.start();
            }

        }
```

Thanks for every kind of response.

Comment: why dont you use the onBackPressed method and use Intent to go back to the MenuActivity

Comment: isnt this automatically the case when i am in the SelectionActivity and i press the backButton ?

Comment: i guess yes but since its not working as it should try doing it the way i proposed

Comment: your welcome! glad for helping

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity